# angularjs: any way to use directive's nested DOM elements as the template?

Tags: angularjs

Please refer to code below.

I'd like to avoid using ng-trasclude, as it's extra wrapping elements, + ng-transclude make own scope. So my goal is to render `<div foo title="FOO!">FOO!</div>` in the end.

`$compile(el.html())(scope)` breaks, since again, it needs a wrapping element.

`template: "<div ng-transclude></div>"` will fail to acces `scope.title`.

Thanks

EDIT
Added plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/R1CAc5pksOVMJoFLhsTu?p=preview
And snippet

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('foo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            title: '@'
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div foo title="FOO">{{title}}</div>
    <span>expecting "FOO!" above this line, but, sigh...</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2

I'd like to keep isolate scope, so that attributes (`<div foo title="FOO!">{{title}}</div>` are then applied via `scope: {title:'@'}`.

EDIT 3

Updated the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You assigned isolated scope for the directive. if you want access it make it as local by given `scope : true`.

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('foo', function() {
  
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
         scope: {
            title : '='
        },
        template : '{{title}}'
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div foo title="'Foo!'"></div>
    <span>expecting "FOO!" above this line, but, sigh...</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah that way I would need to manually assign attributes to the scope , i.g: `$scope.title = $attrs.title;`, while instead I could use `<div foo title="FOO!">{{title}}</div>` along with `scope: {title: '@'}`.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov - I updated the answer you just check

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a template to render `scope.foo` so in your directive you need to specify a template. also if you aren't going to have any values coming from the parent you don't have to put `scope: {}` as a scope will be create for you already

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('foo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span ng-bind="foo"></span>', // <-- add this line
        link: function(scope, el) {
            scope.foo = 'FOO!';
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with it

```
 link: function(scope, el,attr) {
            scope.$parent.foo = "foo"
            scope.foo = 'FOO!';
          }
```

Comment: You must provide some explanation in your answer.